# Append every class field with a constant string in Java

Tags: java, string, field

I have lots of classes representing user screens in the application that I am testing (page objects). Each of the page objects contains various number of elements with wach of the having an ID. I need to declare those IDs. It looks something like this:

```
public class MessagesScreen extends BasePage {

    private static final String backArrowButtonID      = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "backArrow";
    private static final String noMessagesImageID      = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "empty_messages_icon";
    private static final String noMessagesTextViewI    = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "label_no_documents";
    private static final String errorTextViewID        = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "text_error_response";
    private static final String progressBarID          = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "message_list_progress_bar";
    private static final String messagesRecyclerViewID = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "messageList";
    private static final String swipeRefreshLayoutID   = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "swipeRefreshLayout";
    private static final String instantMessageLayoutID = PACKAGE_NAME_ID + "item_instant_message_layout";

}
```

Each of the IDs needs to have the an environmental variable added as above. 
My question is: is there any nifty way of not having to repeat this `PACKAGE_NAME_ID` all the time? Is there a way of automatic assigning the constant string to every new class field?

Comment: Have you looked into using [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)?

Comment: Can you show us where you are using them? Maybe you can prefix them there instead?

Comment: there is absolutly no problem with your code, stop searching for the best way to do something, BTW, static vars should be in uppercase, snake... `PROGRESS_BAR_ID`

Answer (score 2):

Using an `enum` here will improve your code in many ways. In addition to solving your current problem, you'd be using the right tool for constants.

```
enum IdKey {

    BACK_ARROW_BUTTON_ID("backArrow"),
    NO_MESSAGES_IMAGE_ID("empty_messages_icon"),
    NO_MESSAGES_TEXT_VIEW_ID("label_no_documents"),
    ERROR_TEXT_VIEW_ID("text_error_response"),
    PROGRESS_BAR_ID("message_list_progress_bar"),
    MESSAGES_RECYCLER_VIEW_ID("messageList"),
    SWIPE_REFRESH_LAYOUT_ID("swipeRefreshLayout"),
    INSTANT_MESSAGE_LAYOUT_ID("item_instant_message_layout");

    private final String suffix;

    private IdKey(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return BasePage.PACKAGE_NAME_ID + this.suffix;
    }
}
```

And all you'd have to do wherever you were using your fields is just call:

```
IdKey.BACK_ARROW_BUTTON_ID.getSuffix();
```

And the code is both more reliable and cleaner. You can even nest the enum as a private member of `MessagesScreen`.

Comment: Maybe you could change the name of the `getSuffix()` method to i.e. `getId()` +1 for a good idea anyway

Comment: I like your answer (thanks btw), but I see one drawback: having maaany screens, each of them would have to have a private enum with a method and a setter defined. this seems like a lot of boilerplate. Is there any way of e.g. adding an annotation `@Id` to the field, that would append the env variable?

Comment: If this is really such a dynamic kind of functionality, then I wouldn't use fields/properties to start with. Have you considered using a collection/map of strings that you initialize in a constructor or in an initialization block?

Answer (score 1):

I might consider an enum in this case, you can still reference a specific value in the code and override the toString to return your message in the format you want

I have lots of classes representing user screens in the application that I am testing (page objects). Each of the page objects contains various number of elements with wach of the having an ID. I need to declare those IDs. It looks something like this:

```
public enum MessagesScreen {
    BACK_ARROW("backArrow"),
    NO_MESSAGES_IMAGE("empty_messages");

    private String value;
    private Messages(String value) {

    this.value = value;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {

      return PACKAGE_NAME_ID + this.value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you cannot enrich the state of final variables after their valuing, I would do things in the other way : providing a getter that adds the desired prefix.

```
public class MessagesScreen extends BasePage {

    private static final String backArrowButtonID   = "backArrow";
    private static final String noMessagesImageID  = "empty_messages_icon";
    ///...

    public String getIdWithPrefix(String constantValue){
        return PACKAGE_NAME_ID + constantValue;
    }

}
```

Note that with an enum it would be more robust as Strings accept a very large range of possible values whereas enums don't.
It will require you to change many classes but it is worthful.
The ernest_k answer shows that very well.